# Multiple divs grid not being responsive to read more, read less

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with a section and 9 divs inside of it. They show up like 3 columns and 3 rows (I didn't use row and column though, just hardcoded them in CSS i guess to be like that), and each of them goes much like the following:

**(Note: each of the divs has been set in CSS to be 250px high and 430px wide)**

```
<div class="book1">
    <img src="images/book1.jpg" height="250px" width="170px" alt="Book 1">
    <p><button id="shop"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#" 
    target="_blank">  Buy now</a></button><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet, consectetur</p>
</div>
```

Then, following a guide on the web, I added a read more, read less function with Javascript (which I'm absolutely new to) that uses spans and the result is more or less this:

```
<div id="book1" class="book1">
        <img src="images/book1.jpg" height="250px" width="170px" alt="Book 1">
        <p id="bookInfo"><button id="shop"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#" 
        target="_blank">  Buy now</a></button><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<span id="dots">...</span><span 
        id="more">ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
        culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></p>
        <button onclick="showMore();divExpand()" id="showmore">Read more</button>
</div>
```

With the Javascript being this:

```
function showMore() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("showmore");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Leggi di più";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Leggi di meno";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

So far so good, I guess, even if I didn't manage to style the "Read more" button and to let It stay right under the text (here also I hardcoded It's position,  but It's not so clean). The problem is in CSS I set a on hover background change for each div (just a color bg), which is nice, but when the text expands pressing "Read more", words just go outside the div overlapping with the div below. I tried changing overflow in css but didn't solve.
So i came up with an "invented", as-a-beginner, rough solution with javascript:

```
var bookDiv = document.getElementById("book1");

function divExpand() {

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
     bookDiv.style.height = "450px";
  } else {
    bookDiv.style.height = "250px";
  }
}
```

So here I created a var named bookDiv and set It to the div I needed (although I need it for all of them), then created a function "divExpand" and referred to the parameters in the previous function to obtain the result: now when I click "read more" the div actually expands downward, the background hover follows It and all the divs below are just pushed down. Even if I'd like the transition to be smoother and eased, I'd say mission accomplished.

**But**: is there a way to make it more simple? Do I really need javascript for this?

**Also**: would It be better if I used rows and columns to arrange the divs? I've had a lot of problems with them so far, resize, position, dimension, text, images and so on.

Thank you for reading so far, have a nice day.

Comment: Did you read this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp  ?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner yeah that's exactly the guide I used to create the read more read less.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I suggest you to make a code snippet. Anyway, take a look here: https://usefulangle.com/post/54/javascript-read-more-read-less

Answer (score 0):

Here We go.

the problem is with the js

```
var bookDiv = document.getElementById("book1");

function divExpand() {

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
     bookDiv.style.height = "450px";
  } else {
    bookDiv.style.height = "250px"; //dont use fixed height ever
  }
}
```

Here i am overriding your fixed height using css.

```js
    function showMore() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("showmore");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Leggi di più";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Leggi di meno";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}


    var bookDiv = document.getElementById("book1");

    function divExpand() {

        if (dots.style.display === "none") {
         bookDiv.style.height = "450px";
      } else {
        bookDiv.style.height = "250px"; //dont use fixed height ever
      }
    }
```

```css
.wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .wrapper .book1 {
        width: calc(50% - 10px);
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-right: 20px;
        height: auto!important;
        background: red;
    }
    .wrapper .book1:nth-child(2n + 2) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="book1">
    <img src="images/book1.jpg" height="250px" width="170px" alt="Book 1">
    <p><button id="shop"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#" 
    target="_blank">  Buy now</a></button><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit 
    amet, consectetur</p>
</div>
<div id="book1" class="book1">
        <img src="images/book1.jpg" height="250px" width="170px" alt="Book 1">
        <p id="bookInfo"><button id="shop"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#" 
        target="_blank">  Buy now</a></button><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<span id="dots">...</span><span 
        id="more">ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
        culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></p>
        <button onclick="showMore();divExpand()" id="showmore">Read more</button>
</div>
</div>
```